# AttributeError when using Pytest monkeypatch to change fixture object attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures, monkeypatching

In my pytest file `test_foo.py`, I am trying to change the value of `foo.path` to `mock_path` using `monkeypatch`. However, when I try the following, I get an error

> ERROR test_foo.py::test_foo - AttributeError: 'foo' has no attribute 'path'

What should be the correct way to make this change so that `foo` object in `test_foo` will use `mock_path` and pass that test?

**test_foo.py**:

```
import os
import pytest


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test.txt")
        
@pytest.fixture
def foo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(Foo, 'path', 'mock_path')
    return Foo()

def test_foo(foo):
    assert foo.path == "mock_path"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the attribute on the class instead of the class instance, so the error message comes from `monkeypath.setattr` - `Foo` has indeed no attribute `path`, as this is an instance variable.

To fix this, patch the class instance instead:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def foo(monkeypatch):
    inst = Foo()
    monkeypatch.setattr(inst, 'path', 'mock_path')
    return inst
```